# how to fix wordpress get curl on online website

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

on local the code working fine, but on online website

this fakejson working file
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos
but

```php
<?php
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://client.medobay.com/facet/popularPackages/11-10-2020' );
var_dump($response);
```

output:

"cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: client.medobay.com"

Comment: It is possible that the hosting provider blocking to access this site

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Try a different hosting provider (Your site hosting is a shared host or a VPS?)

Comment: If I open your URL, I get JSON objects. cURL error 6 means there is a dns lookup problem. Have a look at what is different from your local environment. Do you have defined a host name for your project? Or maybe try to delete the `https://` from your endpoint URL.

Comment: i tried without `https://` but still not working

Comment: could u help me using anydesk?